# How to get user list?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables in mysql.. I am using mysqli

> **User**
>    - userid
>    - username
>    - email
>
> **Site_A**
>    - userid
>    - username
>    - status
>
> **Site_B**
>    - userid
>    - usename
>    - status

Now I want username from **User** table who is not in either **Site_A** or **Site_B**...
Can you please tell me how I can get username?

I am new to mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATED

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` can help you:

```
SELECT  u.username
FROM User u LEFT JOIN Site_A USING(username)
WHERE Site_A.username IS NULL

UNION

SELECT  u.username
FROM User u LEFT JOIN Site_B USING(username)
  LEFT JOIN Site_B USING(username)
WHERE Site_B.username IS NULL
```

### Original Answer was...

```
SELECT  u.username
FROM User LEFT JOIN Site_A USING(username)
  LEFT JOIN Site_B USING(username)
WHERE Site_A.username IS NULL
  AND Site_B.username IS NULL;
```

Comment: i would prefer using userid(int value) for joining two tables rather than username(varchar).

Comment: @Bhavik Shah sorry. have you editted my answer? I don't know how to accept you modification.

Comment: i mean in site_a and site_b username always same as username in User.. 
when user register at that time i am storing it in to user table then i am moving them to their respected site table.. which is site_a or site_b

Comment: @JungsuHeo: Its ok. Doesn't matter. Just refer my first comment on this answer.

Comment: great working like charm... which will be faster this one or union one?

Comment: @BhavikShah I definitely agree with you if Site_A.userid and Site_B.userid has value. but according to his question, i'm not sure. maybe I misunderstood his question.

Comment: @404NotFound  `UNION` does not matters but sub-query matters. assuming there are a lot rows in Site_A and Site_B. sub-query produces temporary table which contains many rows. but this temporary table does not have any INDEX. I had answered kind of this question. they satisfy with my query rather and using sub-query. try yourself with real large data.

Comment: @404NotFound I updated my query. using LEFT JOIN 2 tables and UNION.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this query:

```
SELECT username
FROM User
WHERE username NOT IN (
    SELECT username
    FROM Site_A
    UNION 
    SELECT username 
    FROM Site_B
)
```

here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c995d/3) for your reference

Comment: good. this works well. but `LEFT JOIN` and checking ` S NULL` is faster than yours. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username
FROM User
WHERE username NOT IN (
SELECT username
FROM Site_A
UNION 
SELECT username 
FROM Site_B
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//tried and tested
SELECT username
FROM User
WHERE username NOT IN (
SELECT username
 FROM Site_A
UNION 
SELECT username 
FROM Site_B
)
```